# I'm using a 2d list, not really sure how to find a minimum value on a, or multiple specific row(s)

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm trying to run a matrix through Dijkstra's algorithm. I have a 2d list comprised of values or inf, I want to scan through the first list and find the smallest value. in the case below 5.

```
lst = [['inf', '10', 'inf', '5', 'inf'],
       ['inf', 'inf', '1', '2', 'inf'], 
       ['inf', 'inf', 'inf', 'inf', '4'], 
       ['inf', '3', '9', 'inf', '2'], 
       ['7', 'inf', '4', 'inf', 'inf']]
```

I know I need to use some version of lst[0:] to specify that list but not really sure exactly how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

`lst[0]` is the first element of `lst` which is the first sublist.

`min(lst[0])` is the smallest value in the first sublist.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your list of lists contains strings.  You likely want to treat the values as floats

```
lst = [['inf', '10', 'inf', '5', 'inf'],
       ['inf', 'inf', '1', '2', 'inf'], 
       ['inf', 'inf', 'inf', 'inf', '4'], 
       ['inf', '3', '9', 'inf', '2'], 
       ['7', 'inf', '4', 'inf', 'inf']]

print(min(float(x) for x in lst[0]))
# 5.0 min of first list
print(min(float(x) for y in lst for x in y))
# 1.0 min of all lists
```

The naive lexicographic minimum of `lst[0]` is `'10'`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. i'm having trouble storing that 5 as a variable now. it's not letting me parse it as a float I think

Comment: or would it be better to convert the inf to just some large number